# Squid Proxy Cache digest

Tags: proxy, centos, squid

I've built a cache hierarchy with three Squid servers and Configure peers with ICP communication and enable cache digests to reduce query messages among peers.

the question here is

where do I find the cache digest? I need to see the details.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

According to the squid proxy website, the cache digests are built and stored in RAM. This has the advantage of offering lower latency when the digests are shared with peers than would be seen if the digests were stored on mechanical storage volumes.